# What's holes in rational or real numbers?

Tags: analysis

> **Theorem 5.5.9** (Existence of least upper bound). Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$. If E has an upper bound, (i.e., $E$ has some upper bound M), then it must have exactly one least upper bound.

> **Theorem 6.4.18** (Completeness of the reals). A sequence $(a_n)^{\infty} _{n=1}$ of
> real numbers is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it is convergent.

> In the language of metric spaces ,Theorem 6.4.18 asserts that the real numbers are a complete metric space - that they do not contain ***“holes”*** the same way the rationals
> do. This property is
> closely related to the least upper bound property (Theorem 5.5.9), and is
> one of the principal characteristics which make the real numbers superior
> to the rational numbers for the purposes of doing analysis

These three descriptions come from the textbook of Tao Analysis. I'm confused with this "***holes***", How does the least upper bound theorem deduce no holes between real numbers while having holes in $\mathbb Q $?  Does it mean every least upper bound is exactly the point of Dedekind cut? If yes,How can we prove it. (What I mean is for example in sets  $A= \{q \leq 0 \text{ or } q^2 \lt 2 \}, B= \{q \gt 0 \text{ and }q^2 \gt 2 \}$,the cut is exactly the least upper bound of set $A$.)

Comment: The point is that in $\Bbb Q$, some sets (such as $\{ x \mid x^2 \lt 2 \}$) have no least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$.  That's because $\Bbb Q$ has a "hole" where $\sqrt 2$ ought to be.

Comment: Why does this theorem 6.4.18 have to do with the completeness? I can't get it. Thank you @RobertShore

Comment: You can tell whether a sequence is Cauchy without ever leaving the space.  So if you have Cauchy sequences that don't converge, each such sequence points to a "hole" that you'd like to be able to fill in by embedding the current space into a larger space.  So, for example, the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ gives you a Cauchy sequence *of rationals* that doesn't converge in $\Bbb Q$.  That indicates that $\Bbb Q$ has a "hole" that $\Bbb R$ "fills in."

Comment: @AndrewLi Theorem 6.4.18 says that the space is complete. If the space were not complete, then there is no guarantee that every Cauchy sequence will be convergent.

Comment: what's "space" you mentioned?

Comment: @AndrewLi In your case the space is the reals (i.e. $\mathbb{R}$).